# "COMMIT" in mysql slow query log with rails application 2.3.5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-performance

I have lots of entries in the slow query log that just have "COMMIT" on them, they take around 3 seconds, which is slow but not awful compared to some other queries.

the entries look like this:

```
COMMIT;
# Time: 120111 14:11:05
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.140228  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1326291065;
COMMIT; 
# Time: 120111 14:14:03
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.036250  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1326291243;
COMMIT;
```

My question is why would rails be issuing a "COMMIT"?

My understanding is it should be using autocommit unless I am doing transactions manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rails performing a transaction** in many case.

For instance if you save a record with a nested model (like topic which has many comments), Rails will wrap updates (1 topic and n comments) in a transaction **to keep your database consistent**.

**EDIT**

As soon as you have two or more queries linked to each other that changed the database you must have a transaction, but it seems that Rails perform a begin/commit even on single queries. I think it's designed this way to avoid useless auto-commit activation/deactivation.

Comment: Interesting, in looking at my rails log I see lots of BEGIN then something then COMMIT, even when not doing nested saves, maybe rails doesnt use autocommit ever....I read that in the docs somewhere, but maybe the docs were wrong..

Comment: I checked a log and you are right, Rails perform a transaction on every queries that change the database. I completed the answer.